# how can I remove two consecutive pluses (+) from a formula/string?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

For example, I have a formula like this:

```
main_var ~ 0 + var1:x + var2:y + var3 + + var4 + (0 + main_var|x_y) + (0 + add_var|x_y) + (1|x_y)
```

How can I remove two consecutive pluses (+) between `var3` and `var4` (and leave only one)?

Comment: if your formula is `f` this works: `f[[3]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[3]] <- quote(var4)` ... but is insane.  use `deparse()` to convert to a string, then `gsub()` with a suitable regular expression, then re-convert to a forrmula

Comment: Ok, thanks! What will be a regex expression to remove two duplicate pluses from a string?

Comment: If the pluses are separated by zero or more spaces: `"\\+\\s*\\+"` and do: `gsub("\\+\\s*\\+", "+", your_string)`

Comment: more specifically `gsub("\\+s*\\+","+",z)` (you want to convert "+ +" to "+"

Comment: You need to be more precise is your description of the problem. Evidently it's not "How can I remove two consecutive pluses (+) between var3 and var4", but "How can I remove two consecutive pluses (+)", and you don't actually want to remove them but you want to replace them one plus sign. Moreover they are not consecutive, as they have characters in between. It seems that you may want to replace, with a plus sign, each string beginning with a plus sign, followed by zero or more spaces followed by another plus sign...

Comment: ...What about `"+  +  +"`. If you replace the first two you are left with ``"+  +"`. Should those then be replaced?. If you were part of a team writing code that someone is paying for all these issues would have to be spelled out when writing code specifications. Writing careful questions at SO is good practice for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
as.formula( gsub( ""\\+s*\\+", "+", deparse(f)))
```

where `f` is your formula.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to edit a formula's component parts without coercing to string. Formulas contain two parts, an expression (the part you write) and an environment (where you write it, maybe with variables in it referred to in the expression). The environment we want to hold on to; the expression we want to change.

Expressions (by which here I mean language objects like symbols and calls, not the narrowly-defined `expression` class) are syntax trees, which behave a bit like lists. They can be subset:

```r
f <- main_var ~ 0 + var1:x + var2:y + var3 + + var4 + (0 + main_var|x_y) + (0 + add_var|x_y) + (1|x_y)

f[[1]]
#> `~`
f[[2]]
#> main_var
f[[3]]
#> 0 + var1:x + var2:y + var3 + +var4 + (0 + main_var | x_y) + (0 + 
#>     add_var | x_y) + (1 | x_y)
f[[3]][[3]]
#> (1 | x_y)
```

and therefore iterated upon. Because they're tree-like structures, to iterate over the whole tree, we need to recurse. Most of the function is pretty typical for recursion (return atomic leaf nodes; recurse over nodes with children), but the tricky part is the condition to identify the part we want to change. If you look at the node in question, it contains a unary (with one argument) `+` call:

```r
f <- main_var ~ 0 + var1:x + var2:y + var3 + + var4 + (0 + main_var|x_y) + (0 + add_var|x_y) + (1|x_y)
f[[3]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[3]]
#> +var4
f[[3]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[3]][[1]]
#> `+`
f[[3]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[3]][[2]]
#> var4
```

All other `+` calls are binary. We can thus check for length-2 nodes where the first node is `+`. As it turns out, getting a `+` expression is also a bit tricky; the simplest is `experssion(+)[[1]]` or `quote(+1)[[1]]`, but once you have that, equality checking works as usual.

Putting the pieces together, and cleaning up by coercing pieces back to expressions and formulas,

```r
remove_unary_plus <- function(expr){
    if (length(expr) == 1) {
        # return atomic elements
        return(expr) 
    } else if (length(expr) == 2 && expr[[1]] == expression(`+`)[[1]]) {
        # for unary plus calls, return the argument without the plus
        return(expr[[2]]) 
    } else {
        # otherwise recurse, simplifying the results back to a language object
        clean_expr <- as.call(lapply(expr, remove_unary_plus))

        # if it's a formula, hold on to the environment
        if (inherits(expr, "formula")) {
            clean_expr <- as.formula(clean_expr, env = environment(expr))
        }

        return(clean_expr)
    }
}

f_clean <- remove_unary_plus(f)
f_clean
#> main_var ~ 0 + var1:x + var2:y + var3 + var4 + (0 + main_var | 
#>     x_y) + (0 + add_var | x_y) + (1 | x_y)
```

And look, it keeps its environment:

```r
str(f)
#> Class 'formula'  language main_var ~ 0 + var1:x + var2:y + var3 + +var4 + (0 + main_var | x_y) +      (0 + add_var | x_y) + (1 | x_y)
#>   ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
str(f_clean)
#> Class 'formula'  language main_var ~ 0 + var1:x + var2:y + var3 + var4 + (0 + main_var | x_y) + (0 +      add_var | x_y) + (1 | x_y)
#>   ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Obviously this is a bit of a pain for day-to-day formula manipulation, but, well, it's possible, maybe useful for programmatic usage, and (to me, at least) interesting.

Comment: I agree that this is the "correct" robust answer, but it's such a pain in the butt that I only build systems like this when necessary ...

Comment: Yeah, I wish tools for working with recursion in R were just a little better. `Recall`, `rapply`, `purrr::modify_depth`, `pryr::modify_lang`, etc. are just not quite flexible or powerful enough, so it's just easier to use regex. Maybe I should write another package.